# Corda check if node is in drain mode inside Service

Tags: corda

Suppose I have a Corda service:

```
@CordaService
class MyService(serviceHub: AppServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken()
```

Is there a way to check if my node is in Drain mode inside this service?
I tried to find this information inside `AppServiceHub` instance, but could not.
I found out that there is also a class `ServiceHubInternal` which has `nodeProperties.flowsDrainingMode.isEnabled()` exactly what I need. But I don't know how can I get an instance of `ServiceHubInternal` inside Corda Service.

Even if I try a suggested solution to add `corda-node` as a dependency and try to cast `ServiceHubInternal sHI = (ServiceHubInternal) getServiceHub();` I get `ClassCastException - net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$AppServiceHubImpl cannot be cast to net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal`

UPDATE

Well interestingly, when I do the same thing inside the Flow itself it works, so the `serviceHub` inside `FlowLogic` can be casted to `ServiceHubInternal` but the one inside `CordaService` cannot. is it the way it should work? Are there any workarounds to get the `ServiceHubInternal` instance inside CordaService ?

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `corda-node` dependency to access `ServiceHubInternal`.

Add below to you build.gradle file in dependencies section:

```
cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node:$corda_release_version"
```

You should now be able to access ServiceHubInternal and check for draining mode as below:

```
 ServiceHubInternal sHI = (ServiceHubInternal) getServiceHub();
 sHI.getNodeProperties().getFlowsDrainingMode().isEnabled();
```

Comment: Thanks, but having corda-node as a dependency does not solve the problem, I continue to get "ClassCastException - net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$AppServiceHubImpl cannot be cast to net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal"

Comment: That's weird I am able to use it in the flow, without any problem. I remember you mentioned using Braid on slack, it may have something to do with that.

Comment: Yes I use it, but how can braid change the serviceHub instance that I get inside my service? I will try to create a totally new service and try it